# Unable to expose web service in derived MVC project

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, wsdl

I am developing a Spring MVC project that derives from a Spring-MVC-based framework. I can define any number of Spring XML context file in my project, and those provided by the platform will be loaded automatically.

I have defined a WSDL (so contract-first) and then compiled this WSDL using CXF's `wsdl2java` tool into an annotated `SEI`.

I could use CXF 3 right away but I have been asked, as an experiment, to expose the service using `spring-ws`.

This service, for simplicity purposes, has no authentication or special stuff.
I have tried to follow `spring-ws` guide but got totally lost. The key point is that I don't understand under what URL does my `@Endpoint` respond. I could enquire it with `soapui` with ease if I knew.

So far I have defined the WSDL with a simple operation definition (details redacted for simplicity)

```
<wsdl:portType name="SgaRuotaService">
    <wsdl:operation name="UploadModelloUnico">
        <wsdl:input message="sgaws:UploadModelloUnicoRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="sgaws:UploadModelloUnicoResponse" />
        <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="sgaws:UploadModelloUnicoFault"></wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

The SEI is the following

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.acme.com/schemas/sgaws/v1", name = "SgaRuotaService")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@Generated(value = "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava", date = "2017-02-07T15:33:48.958+01:00", comments = "Apache CXF 3.1.9")
public interface SgaRuotaService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "UploadModelloUnico", action = "http://www.acme.com/schemas/sga-ruota-push/UploadModelloUnico")
    @WebResult(name = "UploadModelloUnicoResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.acme.com/schemas/sgaws/v1", partName = "parameters")
    @Generated(value = "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava", date = "2017-02-07T15:33:48.958+01:00")
    public UploadModelloUnicoResponseType uploadModelloUnico(
        @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "UploadModelloUnicoRequest", targetNamespace = "http://www.acme.com/schemas/sgaws/v1")
        UploadModelloUnicoRequestType parameters
    ) throws UploadModelloUnicoFault;
}
```

I have derived it..

```
@Endpoint("sgaRuotaService")
@RequestMapping("/pub/sgaRuotaService") //further attempt to make it work
public class RuotaServiceEndpoint implements SgaRuotaService
{

    private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    //@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://www.acme.com/schemas/sgaruota/v1", localPart = "UploadModelloUnicoRequestType")
    @ResponsePayload
    @SoapAction("http://www.acme.com/schemas/sga-ruota-push/UploadModelloUnico")
    public UploadModelloUnicoResponseType uploadModelloUnico(@RequestPayload UploadModelloUnicoRequestType parameters) throws UploadModelloUnicoFault
    {
        log.info("Ruota service");
        return null;
    }

}
```

And then the context file. After messing a lot with the configuration I have come with the following

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.3.xsd"
>

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="oxmMarshaller" context-path="com.acme.sga.ws.ruota" />

    <!-- WEB SERVICE -->

    <sws:annotation-driven marshaller="oxmMarshaller" unmarshaller="oxmMarshaller" />
    <sws:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor" />
    </sws:interceptors>
    <sws:static-wsdl id="/pub/sgaRuota.wsdl" location="classpath:META-INF/wsdl/sga-ruota-service.wsdl" />

    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" id="oxmMarshaller"> -->
    <!-- <property name="packagesToScan"> -->
    <!-- <array> -->
    <!-- <value>com.acme.sga</value> -->
    <!-- </array> -->
    <!-- </property> -->
    <!-- </bean> -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageFactory">
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory" factory-method="newInstance" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter" />



    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/pub/sgaRuota.wsdl">/pub/sgaRuota.wsdl</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageDispatcher" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping" />

<!--     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" /> -->


</beans>
```

The web application starts and works (the web page part...) but I can't load the WSDL in any way, nor ping the service endpoint.

I can post additional fragments on demand, but the question is: how do I expose the service endpoint under context's `/pub` directory which is "incidentally" not under `spring-security`?

Comment: Try this documentation from Spring http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html.

Comment: With all the due respect, I spent a few hours over that document. I still haven't found how to use correctly the `MessageDispatcher` in an existing context and correctly hardcode the path to each `@Endpoint` I create (for now only one). Mine is the case where the wsdl is in the classpath and I already generated the SEI. Maybe I could ask directly: "How does `SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` control the URL binding if `@RequestMapping` does not work? And also when the `@SoapAction` uses a URL different from localhost